# Google Drive and the Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3

Does anyone know how Google Drive works with the Raspberry Pi?
I am at a school that uses G Suite for Education and would like to be able to have programmes auto-update on Google Drive when they are edited on the pi and auto-update on the Pi when edited on Drive.
Could I code this, or would Google block this connection between their servers and the Raspberry Pi? 
Can you set up the Pi to output files to Google drive as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be helpful. To mount the Drive and Outbox. Go through the link once.

[How to mount your google drive on Raspbian RPI with GDriveFS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=109587)